# django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: Recruiter_jobs table not found error?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

I Am doing a project in Django and I have created some models in my project and after migrating it gives me something error like Django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table:  Recruiter_jobs, but I think I have all the tables registered in admin also. but still, it showing an error...

here's my **models.py**

```
class empDetail(models.Model):
    cmpName=models.CharField("Company Name ",max_length=30)
    role=models.CharField("role ",max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.empEmail

class jobs(models.Model):
    location=models.CharField("Location ",max_length=30)
    desc=models.CharField("Descriptions ",max_length=3000)
    role=models.CharField("role ",max_length=10)
    sal=models.CharField("salary ",max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.desc



class candetail(models.Model):
    location=models.CharField("Locations ",max_length=30,default="") 
    role=models.CharField("Role ",max_length=100,default="")
    cv=models.FileField(upload_to="media/canDetails/")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.location

class availablejob(models.Model):
    cmpny=models.CharField("Company Name",max_length=100,default="")
    location=models.CharField("Location ",max_length=30)
    desc=models.CharField("Descriptions ",max_length=3000)
    role=models.CharField("Role ",max_length=100)
    sal=models.CharField("Salary ",max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.role


    
    
    class empDetails(models.Model):
        cmpName=models.CharField("Company Name ",max_length=30)
        role=models.CharField("role ",max_length=20)
        cv=models.FileField(upload_to="media/empDetails/")
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.empEmail
```

heres the **logs below**

```
(env) PS C:\Users\ashwi\Documents\GitHub\AMCH\AMCH_Recruiter> python manage.py migrate       
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: Recruiter, admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying Recruiter.0008_delete_jobs...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\Documents\GitHub\AMCH\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\Documents\GitHub\AMCH\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: Recruiter_jobs

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\Documents\GitHub\AMCH\AMCH_Recruiter\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\Documents\GitHub\AMCH\AMCH_Recruiter\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\Documents\GitHub\AMCH\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\Documents\GitHub\AMCH\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\Documents\GitHub\AMCH\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\Documents\GitHub\AMCH\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\Documents\GitHub\AMCH\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\Documents\GitHub\AMCH\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 244, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\Documents\GitHub\AMCH\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\Documents\GitHub\AMCH\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\Documents\GitHub\AMCH\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\Documents\GitHub\AMCH\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 126, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\Documents\GitHub\AMCH\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py", line 269, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.delete_model(model)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\Documents\GitHub\AMCH\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 311, in delete_model
    super().delete_model(model)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\Documents\GitHub\AMCH\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 363, in delete_model
    self.execute(self.sql_delete_table % {
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\Documents\GitHub\AMCH\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 145, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\Documents\GitHub\AMCH\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\Documents\GitHub\AMCH\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\Documents\GitHub\AMCH\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\Documents\GitHub\AMCH\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\Documents\GitHub\AMCH\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\Documents\GitHub\AMCH\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\ashwi\Documents\GitHub\AMCH\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: Recruiter_jobs
(env) PS C:\Users\ashwi\Documents\GitHub\AMCH\AMCH_Recruiter>
```

what's the error cause here? I have even tried to delete this model but still no changes... it gives the same error.
please suggest any solution for it.

Comment: are you running makemigrations command before running migrate command ?

Comment: @VimalanE yes, i am first running makemigrations then migrate command. in any order it throwing the same error when i run `python manag.py migrate` command

Comment: try deleting .py and .pyc from migrations directory and run makemigrations <app_name> and do migrate

Comment: Thank you @VimalanE ,It worked.